# How to deploy metabase with Laravel Forge

Tags: nginx-config, metabase, laravel-forge

I installed Metabase as a service on the server and I have it booted but I have a problem in the Nginx configuration. I am using Laravel Forge for the project and I need to change the Nginx configuration to be able to access Metabase.

My current default configuration file is the following:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/default/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/default/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/default/after/*;
```

According to metabase docs, adding the following statement i should be able to access the metabase:

```
# sample nginx.conf
# proxy requests to Metabase instance
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name your.domain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

When I add the proxy_pass with the configuration as follows, the server fails: it returns a 502 Bad Gateway error and a connection time out when I try to access port 3000.

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

What should I change in the nginx configuration to be able to access metabase? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For other people who don't know about systems, I had the port blocked.

To see if you have port 3000 open, use

```
ufw status
```

.

If it does not appear, open the port with

```
sudo ufw allow 3000
```

That's it, now it's working